# How to set image/WebView height/width to match the parent?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-animation

Hello all and good day.

I found it easy to display GIF animations using WebView as it is fairly easy and simple.

Now the GIF I'm displaying is of the size 800x800px. What I want is that this GIF to fit the screen available to it, possibly to match parent something like that, so that one does not have to scroll or zoom in/out the picture. It just fits automatically on any screen available to it.

My device used for experimenting is: GT-I9100/Samsung Galaxy SII which has the screen size of 800x480px.

Here's a snippet of code from my main activity:

```
HToad view = new HToad(this, "file:///android_asset/hypnotoad.gif");
view.setInitialScale(30);
view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
setContentView(view);
```

This is the HToad class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class HToad extends WebView {

    public HToad(Context context, String path) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        loadUrl(path);
    }

}
```

I tried using various settings like LayoutParams and IntialSize etc, none of which helped me to achieve what I want.

I'm using JAVA for WebView, not defining WebView in XML.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to load your gif with the loadData method instead loadUrl and add a css style like this:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    img {max-width: 100%;height:initial;}
</style>
```

And in the end you must get something like this:

```
setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
loadData("<style type='text/css'> img {max-width: 100%;height:initial;}</style>" +
         "<img align='middle' src='file:///android_asset/hypnotoad.gif'/>", "text/html", "utf-8");
reload();
```

I hope I helped you.